# Performance wise, Why isnt facebook loading all JS files at once?

Tags: performance, seo

I am looking at the html code in facebook after logging in and they seem to be doing a lot of requests for JS files (up to 20 according to firebug).
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577850/why-doesnt-facebook-combine-its-css-js-files) here which pretty much sums up what I initially wanted to know, but that question is rather old now, the blog post it links to is from 2010, and facebook does not seem to care about SEO.

So, while I understand that facebook needs to load many JS and CSS files (instead of one JS and one CSS file), my question is towards more general purpose websites and the state of web crawlers.
Should we be concerned that these techniques (loading main content via ajax) will affect web crawlers (googlebot and friends)?

I want to improve performance and loading 'need-it-for-later' content (text/js/css) seems like a good idea, but not if its not going to be available (the content of course) for crawlers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81766

> While Googlebot is great at understanding the structure of HTML links, it can have difficulty finding its way around sites which use JavaScript for navigation. We're working on doing a better job of understanding JavaScript, but your best bet for creating a site that's crawlable by Google and other search engines is to provide HTML links to your content.

googlebot and most search engines crawlers don't execute javascript code , this is because loading javascript and css implies page rendering which heat performance and no spider can live with that.

however, a spider can take a peek at js code to check for specific patterns (like for example a blackhat technique is being used).

the best (but hard) solution is to provide basic content for agents that can't execute javascript (main page content must be available) and an optimized one with more features for modern browsers